# Which lib folder should I use for my portable library targeting net45, asp.net core 5.0 and windows 8?

Tags: nuget, nuget-package, portable-class-library, nuget-spec

I am currently developing a portable library in C# that I want to publish on the NuGet official feed. I have published assemblies as NuGet packages before, but they were written against a single framework (.NET 4.0).

Now I'm confused how I should organize my lib folder in my NuGet package - my portable library can be used with .NET 4.5, ASP.NET Core 5.0, Windows 8, Windows Phone 8.1 and Windows Phone Silverlight 8 projects.

[image]

I tried to look up the framework profiles and their corresponding NuGet abbreviations, but I couldn't find them in the official documentation. [Stephen Cleary gathered up profiles a while ago](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/05/framework-profiles-in-net.html), but his list does not contain the profile for ASP.NET Core 5.0.

**My actual question is: how should I structure the lib folder of my NuGet package?** What is the profile name for portable libraries that target the framework versions mentioned above? And if I get that very profile name, is the assembly properly referenced in a non-portable library project (e.g. .NET 4.5 or WinRT)? Or should I make subfolders for the different framework version and copy the exact same assembly in all of them (which would largely increase the size of the package)? I habe seen some packages (like xunit.assert) doing it this way in NuGet Package Explorer.

[image: Structure of xunit.assert]

Comment: From where do you know that your library will work for "ASP.NET Core 5.0"? There is only "ASP.NET 5" for RC1, or "ASP.NET Core 1.0" for RC2 and above.

Comment: @LexLi these are the exact targeting names in the Visual Studio 2015 project preferences (see screenshot above).

Comment: If you open the .csproj file in a text editor, you'll see the profile name under TargetFrameworkProfile. I think yours is 259.

Comment: Damien, you are correct - thanks!

Comment: As @DamienDennehy showed you it is profile259, you can easily find the monikers to use in Stephen's blog post. This question is answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The actual folder name that one has to use in this case is the following one:

`portable-net45+wp80+win8+wpa81+dnxcore50`

[image: lib folder name to use for profile 259]